# Highcharts datetime axis overlap with a long time series

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to show time series information that could potentially span a large period (a thousand years or more). I can't seem to get the time axis labels not to overlap though. No amount of playing with the various tick controls seems to help, even setting tickPixelInterval to arbitrarily large values does not reduce the number of ticks.

Here's an example thrown together from one of the highcharts demos http://jsfiddle.net/cjUVR/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate from 2006 through 2008'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 365,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
            data: [
                0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451,    0.8418, 0.8264,    0.8258, 0.8232,    0.8233, 0.8258,
                0.8283, 0.8278, 0.8256, 0.8292,    0.8239, 0.8239,    0.8245, 0.8265,    0.8261, 0.8269,
                0.8273, 0.8244, 0.8244, 0.8172,    0.8139, 0.8146,    0.8164, 0.82,    0.8269, 0.8269,
                0.8269, 0.8258, 0.8247, 0.8286,    0.8289, 0.8316,    0.832, 0.8333,    0.8352, 0.8357,
                0.8355, 0.8354, 0.8403, 0.8403,    0.8406, 0.8403,    0.8396, 0.8418,    0.8409, 0.8384,
                0.8386, 0.8372, 0.839, 0.84, 0.8389, 0.84, 0.8423, 0.8423, 0.8435, 0.8422,
                0.838, 0.8373, 0.8316, 0.8303,    0.8303, 0.8302,    0.8369, 0.84, 0.8385, 0.84,
                0.8401, 0.8402, 0.8381, 0.8351,    0.8314, 0.8273,    0.8213, 0.8207,    0.8207, 0.8215,
                0.8242, 0.8273, 0.8301, 0.8346,    0.8312, 0.8312,    0.8312, 0.8306,    0.8327, 0.8282,
                0.824, 0.8255, 0.8256, 0.8273, 0.8209, 0.8151, 0.8149, 0.8213, 0.8273, 0.8273,
                0.8261, 0.8252, 0.824, 0.8262, 0.8258, 0.8261, 0.826, 0.8199, 0.8153, 0.8097,
                0.8101, 0.8119, 0.8107, 0.8105,    0.8084, 0.8069,    0.8047, 0.8023,    0.7965, 0.7919,
                0.7921, 0.7922, 0.7934, 0.7918,    0.7915, 0.787, 0.7861, 0.7861, 0.7853, 0.7867,
                0.7827, 0.7834, 0.7766, 0.7751, 0.7739, 0.7767, 0.7802, 0.7788, 0.7828, 0.7816,
                0.7829, 0.783, 0.7829, 0.7781, 0.7811, 0.7831, 0.7826, 0.7855, 0.7855, 0.7845,
                0.7798, 0.7777, 0.7822, 0.7785, 0.7744, 0.7743, 0.7726, 0.7766, 0.7806, 0.785,
                0.7907, 0.7912, 0.7913, 0.7931, 0.7952, 0.7951, 0.7928, 0.791, 0.7913, 0.7912,
                0.7941, 0.7953, 0.7921, 0.7919, 0.7968, 0.7999, 0.7999, 0.7974, 0.7942, 0.796,
                0.7969, 0.7862, 0.7821, 0.7821, 0.7821, 0.7811, 0.7833, 0.7849, 0.7819, 0.7809,
                0.7809, 0.7827, 0.7848, 0.785, 0.7873, 0.7894, 0.7907, 0.7909, 0.7947, 0.7987,
                0.799, 0.7927, 0.79, 0.7878, 0.7878, 0.7907, 0.7922, 0.7937, 0.786, 0.787,
                0.7838, 0.7838, 0.7837, 0.7836, 0.7806, 0.7825, 0.7798, 0.777, 0.777, 0.7772,
                0.7793, 0.7788, 0.7785, 0.7832, 0.7865, 0.7865, 0.7853, 0.7847, 0.7809, 0.778,
                0.7799, 0.78, 0.7801, 0.7765, 0.7785, 0.7811, 0.782, 0.7835, 0.7845, 0.7844,
                0.782, 0.7811, 0.7795, 0.7794, 0.7806, 0.7794, 0.7794, 0.7778, 0.7793, 0.7808,
                0.7824, 0.787, 0.7894, 0.7893, 0.7882, 0.7871, 0.7882, 0.7871, 0.7878, 0.79,
                0.7901, 0.7898, 0.7879, 0.7886, 0.7858, 0.7814, 0.7825, 0.7826, 0.7826, 0.786,
                0.7878, 0.7868, 0.7883, 0.7893, 0.7892, 0.7876, 0.785, 0.787, 0.7873, 0.7901,
                0.7936, 0.7939, 0.7938, 0.7956, 0.7975, 0.7978, 0.7972, 0.7995, 0.7995, 0.7994,
                0.7976, 0.7977, 0.796, 0.7922, 0.7928, 0.7929, 0.7948, 0.797, 0.7953, 0.7907,
                0.7872, 0.7852, 0.7852, 0.786, 0.7862, 0.7836, 0.7837, 0.784, 0.7867, 0.7867,
                0.7869, 0.7837, 0.7827, 0.7825, 0.7779, 0.7791, 0.779, 0.7787, 0.78, 0.7807,
                0.7803, 0.7817, 0.7799, 0.7799, 0.7795, 0.7801, 0.7765, 0.7725, 0.7683, 0.7641,
                0.7639, 0.7616, 0.7608, 0.759, 0.7582, 0.7539, 0.75, 0.75, 0.7507, 0.7505,
                0.7516, 0.7522, 0.7531, 0.7577, 0.7577, 0.7582, 0.755, 0.7542, 0.7576, 0.7616,
                0.7648, 0.7648, 0.7641, 0.7614, 0.757, 0.7587, 0.7588, 0.762, 0.762, 0.7617,
                0.7618, 0.7615, 0.7612, 0.7596, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.7547, 0.7549, 0.7613,
                0.7655, 0.7693, 0.7694, 0.7688, 0.7678, 0.7708, 0.7727, 0.7749, 0.7741, 0.7741,
                0.7732, 0.7727, 0.7737, 0.7724, 0.7712, 0.772, 0.7721, 0.7717, 0.7704, 0.769,
                0.7711, 0.774, 0.7745, 0.7745, 0.774, 0.7716, 0.7713, 0.7678, 0.7688, 0.7718,
                0.7718, 0.7728, 0.7729, 0.7698, 0.7685, 0.7681, 0.769, 0.769, 0.7698, 0.7699,
                0.7651, 0.7613, 0.7616, 0.7614, 0.7614, 0.7607, 0.7602, 0.7611, 0.7622, 0.7615,
                0.7598, 0.7598, 0.7592, 0.7573, 0.7566, 0.7567, 0.7591, 0.7582, 0.7585, 0.7613,
                0.7631, 0.7615, 0.76, 0.7613, 0.7627, 0.7627, 0.7608, 0.7583, 0.7575, 0.7562,
                0.752, 0.7512, 0.7512, 0.7517, 0.752, 0.7511, 0.748, 0.7509, 0.7531, 0.7531,
                0.7527, 0.7498, 0.7493, 0.7504, 0.75, 0.7491, 0.7491, 0.7485, 0.7484, 0.7492,
                0.7471, 0.7459, 0.7477, 0.7477, 0.7483, 0.7458, 0.7448, 0.743, 0.7399, 0.7395,
                0.7395, 0.7378, 0.7382, 0.7362, 0.7355, 0.7348, 0.7361, 0.7361, 0.7365, 0.7362,
                0.7331, 0.7339, 0.7344, 0.7327, 0.7327, 0.7336, 0.7333, 0.7359, 0.7359, 0.7372,
                0.736, 0.736, 0.735, 0.7365, 0.7384, 0.7395, 0.7413, 0.7397, 0.7396, 0.7385,
                0.7378, 0.7366, 0.74, 0.7411, 0.7406, 0.7405, 0.7414, 0.7431, 0.7431, 0.7438,
                0.7443, 0.7443, 0.7443, 0.7434, 0.7429, 0.7442, 0.744, 0.7439, 0.7437, 0.7437,
                0.7429, 0.7403, 0.7399, 0.7418, 0.7468, 0.748, 0.748, 0.749, 0.7494, 0.7522,
                0.7515, 0.7502, 0.7472, 0.7472, 0.7462, 0.7455, 0.7449, 0.7467, 0.7458, 0.7427,
                0.7427, 0.743, 0.7429, 0.744, 0.743, 0.7422, 0.7388, 0.7388, 0.7369, 0.7345,
                0.7345, 0.7345, 0.7352, 0.7341, 0.7341, 0.734, 0.7324, 0.7272, 0.7264, 0.7255,
                0.7258, 0.7258, 0.7256, 0.7257, 0.7247, 0.7243, 0.7244, 0.7235, 0.7235, 0.7235,
                0.7235, 0.7262, 0.7288, 0.7301, 0.7337, 0.7337, 0.7324, 0.7297, 0.7317, 0.7315,
                0.7288, 0.7263, 0.7263, 0.7242, 0.7253, 0.7264, 0.727, 0.7312, 0.7305, 0.7305,
                0.7318, 0.7358, 0.7409, 0.7454, 0.7437, 0.7424, 0.7424, 0.7415, 0.7419, 0.7414,
                0.7377, 0.7355, 0.7315, 0.7315, 0.732, 0.7332, 0.7346, 0.7328, 0.7323, 0.734,
                0.734, 0.7336, 0.7351, 0.7346, 0.7321, 0.7294, 0.7266, 0.7266, 0.7254, 0.7242,
                0.7213, 0.7197, 0.7209, 0.721, 0.721, 0.721, 0.7209, 0.7159, 0.7133, 0.7105,
                0.7099, 0.7099, 0.7093, 0.7093, 0.7076, 0.707, 0.7049, 0.7012, 0.7011, 0.7019,
                0.7046, 0.7063, 0.7089, 0.7077, 0.7077, 0.7077, 0.7091, 0.7118, 0.7079, 0.7053,
                0.705, 0.7055, 0.7055, 0.7045, 0.7051, 0.7051, 0.7017, 0.7, 0.6995, 0.6994,
                0.7014, 0.7036, 0.7021, 0.7002, 0.6967, 0.695, 0.695, 0.6939, 0.694, 0.6922,
                0.6919, 0.6914, 0.6894, 0.6891, 0.6904, 0.689, 0.6834, 0.6823, 0.6807, 0.6815,
                0.6815, 0.6847, 0.6859, 0.6822, 0.6827, 0.6837, 0.6823, 0.6822, 0.6822, 0.6792,
                0.6746, 0.6735, 0.6731, 0.6742, 0.6744, 0.6739, 0.6731, 0.6761, 0.6761, 0.6785,
                0.6818, 0.6836, 0.6823, 0.6805, 0.6793, 0.6849, 0.6833, 0.6825, 0.6825, 0.6816,
                0.6799, 0.6813, 0.6809, 0.6868, 0.6933, 0.6933, 0.6945, 0.6944, 0.6946, 0.6964,
                0.6965, 0.6956, 0.6956, 0.695, 0.6948, 0.6928, 0.6887, 0.6824, 0.6794, 0.6794,
                0.6803, 0.6855, 0.6824, 0.6791, 0.6783, 0.6785, 0.6785, 0.6797, 0.68, 0.6803,
                0.6805, 0.676, 0.677, 0.677, 0.6736, 0.6726, 0.6764, 0.6821, 0.6831, 0.6842,
                0.6842, 0.6887, 0.6903, 0.6848, 0.6824, 0.6788, 0.6814, 0.6814, 0.6797, 0.6769,
                0.6765, 0.6733, 0.6729, 0.6758, 0.6758, 0.675, 0.678, 0.6833, 0.6856, 0.6903,
                0.6896, 0.6896, 0.6882, 0.6879, 0.6862, 0.6852, 0.6823, 0.6813, 0.6813, 0.6822,
                0.6802, 0.6802, 0.6784, 0.6748, 0.6747, 0.6747, 0.6748, 0.6733, 0.665, 0.6611,
                0.6583, 0.659, 0.659, 0.6581, 0.6578, 0.6574, 0.6532, 0.6502, 0.6514, 0.6514,
                0.6507, 0.651, 0.6489, 0.6424, 0.6406, 0.6382, 0.6382, 0.6341, 0.6344, 0.6378,
                0.6439, 0.6478, 0.6481, 0.6481, 0.6494, 0.6438, 0.6377, 0.6329, 0.6336, 0.6333,
                0.6333, 0.633, 0.6371, 0.6403, 0.6396, 0.6364, 0.6356, 0.6356, 0.6368, 0.6357,
                0.6354, 0.632, 0.6332, 0.6328, 0.6331, 0.6342, 0.6321, 0.6302, 0.6278, 0.6308,
                0.6324, 0.6324, 0.6307, 0.6277, 0.6269, 0.6335, 0.6392, 0.64, 0.6401, 0.6396,
                0.6407, 0.6423, 0.6429, 0.6472, 0.6485, 0.6486, 0.6467, 0.6444, 0.6467, 0.6509,
                0.6478, 0.6461, 0.6461, 0.6468, 0.6449, 0.647, 0.6461, 0.6452, 0.6422, 0.6422,
                0.6425, 0.6414, 0.6366, 0.6346, 0.635, 0.6346, 0.6346, 0.6343, 0.6346, 0.6379,
                0.6416, 0.6442, 0.6431, 0.6431, 0.6435, 0.644, 0.6473, 0.6469, 0.6386, 0.6356,
                0.634, 0.6346, 0.643, 0.6452, 0.6467, 0.6506, 0.6504, 0.6503, 0.6481, 0.6451,
                0.645, 0.6441, 0.6414, 0.6409, 0.6409, 0.6428, 0.6431, 0.6418, 0.6371, 0.6349,
                0.6333, 0.6334, 0.6338, 0.6342, 0.632, 0.6318, 0.637, 0.6368, 0.6368, 0.6383,
                0.6371, 0.6371, 0.6355, 0.632, 0.6277, 0.6276, 0.6291, 0.6274, 0.6293, 0.6311,
                0.631, 0.6312, 0.6312, 0.6304, 0.6294, 0.6348, 0.6378, 0.6368, 0.6368, 0.6368,
                0.636, 0.637, 0.6418, 0.6411, 0.6435, 0.6427, 0.6427, 0.6419, 0.6446, 0.6468,
                0.6487, 0.6594, 0.6666, 0.6666, 0.6678, 0.6712, 0.6705, 0.6718, 0.6784, 0.6811,
                0.6811, 0.6794, 0.6804, 0.6781, 0.6756, 0.6735, 0.6763, 0.6762, 0.6777, 0.6815,
                0.6802, 0.678, 0.6796, 0.6817, 0.6817, 0.6832, 0.6877, 0.6912, 0.6914, 0.7009,
                0.7012, 0.701, 0.7005, 0.7076, 0.7087, 0.717, 0.7105, 0.7031, 0.7029, 0.7006,
                0.7035, 0.7045, 0.6956, 0.6988, 0.6915, 0.6914, 0.6859, 0.6778, 0.6815, 0.6815,
                0.6843, 0.6846, 0.6846, 0.6923, 0.6997, 0.7098, 0.7188, 0.7232, 0.7262, 0.7266,
                0.7359, 0.7368, 0.7337, 0.7317, 0.7387, 0.7467, 0.7461, 0.7366, 0.7319, 0.7361,
                0.7437, 0.7432, 0.7461, 0.7461, 0.7454, 0.7549, 0.7742, 0.7801, 0.7903, 0.7876,
                0.7928, 0.7991, 0.8007, 0.7823, 0.7661, 0.785, 0.7863, 0.7862, 0.7821, 0.7858,
                0.7731, 0.7779, 0.7844, 0.7866, 0.7864, 0.7788, 0.7875, 0.7971, 0.8004, 0.7857,
                0.7932, 0.7938, 0.7927, 0.7918, 0.7919, 0.7989, 0.7988, 0.7949, 0.7948, 0.7882,
                0.7745, 0.771, 0.775, 0.7791, 0.7882, 0.7882, 0.7899, 0.7905, 0.7889, 0.7879,
                0.7855, 0.7866, 0.7865, 0.7795, 0.7758, 0.7717, 0.761, 0.7497, 0.7471, 0.7473,
                0.7407, 0.7288, 0.7074, 0.6927, 0.7083, 0.7191, 0.719, 0.7153, 0.7156, 0.7158,
                0.714, 0.7119, 0.7129, 0.7129, 0.7049, 0.7095
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

I'd prefer solutions that don't require any specific knowledge of the data as it is not always over such a long period - but anything is helpful (and could be conditionally applied).

Comment: try to re adjust the point interval to days and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Highcharts datetime axis is not prepared to display data for 1000 of years :) But simple linear axis with `labels.formatter` should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/cjUVR/3/

Comment: Thank you. This should work perfectly, just need to detect the right range and switch over to this type of labeling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the tickInterval, min, max in xAxis declaration. Can see below:

```
xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
       tickInterval: 6 * 30 * 24 * 3460 * 1000, //6 months ticks              
       min: Date.UTC(2006, 1, 1),
       max: Date.UTC(2008, 12, 1)
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work, see http://jsfiddle.net/cjUVR/4/ for an example. It seems the datetime axis isn't able to figure it out even when told specifically what to do. Pawel's answer provides a good alternative until this gets addressed though.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Seems like Pawel's answer provides what you need. Didn't know about Formatter.